# Copying Files to Remote Server in Network

Tags: angular, azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I'm working with Azure DevOps for the first time and I'm trying to complete my build/release pipeline. I'm working with a Node.js/Angular frontend application and I want to publish the files from the /dist file onto a remote server within my network.

I have the files I need being built and zipped up, but I'm running into trouble copying the files over to my server. I'm using a Windows Machine File Copy task. The machine is located in my network, not Azure, so it feels like that is the problem and it makes sense why I can't just do a copy.

I am getting the following: Failed to Create PSDrive with Destination: '\my_server_name\d$\webapps\test' The network path not found

What should I be doing instead?

Comment: Well, the problem is pretty clear, you are trying to copy the file to a share folder which not exists .

Comment: what are my options for copying data from Azure DevOps to a shared folder in my network?

Comment: I'm using the Agent Folder as a staging folder and then copy the dist file to the destination - NOT A SHARE FOLDER.
If you would like to copy the dist folder to share folder, just create one.

Comment: you're copying it manually once it's done? I'm not sure I'm following. do you have a link you could point me to?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a self-hosted agent that resides within your network, then Windows Machine File Copy will **create** a temporary share to use to copy files. You specify the path **on the target machine** to use, such as `D:\ArtifactStaging`.

If you're using the Microsoft-provided host agent, then there's no way you can copy files to your on-prem server, unless that on-prem server is accessible over the internet and has appropriate ports open, which I would not recommend. You'll have to install a private, self-hosted agent that resides within your network.

Comment: my problem seems to be accessing the Target Machine.

Comment: Per the error message you provided, the problem isn't accessing the target machine, it's that you specified a share. You don't need to specify a share. You need to specify a drive and folder, the Windows machine file copy task **creates the share for you**.

Comment: Failed to Create PSDrive with Destination: '\\xx.xxx.x.xxx\D$\testing_azure', ErrorMessage: 'The network path was not found'

Comment: Azure isn't able to access my remote machine it seems. I'm looking for a way to make that possible.

Comment: Wait. You're using the **hosted** build agent? If so, then there's no way you can copy files to your on-prem server, unless that on-prem server is accessible over the internet and has appropriate ports open, which I would *not* recommend. You'll have to install a private, self-hosted agent that resides within your network.

Comment: @DanielMann: Hey Daniel how can we copy files to GitHub? Can you help me with this?

Comment: @JagratiModi You can ask a new question. You don't "copy files" to GitHub. You push changes you make to a repository.